# perl counter doesnt work - keeps on entering into the while loop

Tags: perl

I have this perl code, and what I want it to do is to search for the strings and do something if its find a match.

When it finds a match, I want it to increase the counter by 1 so it will not go all over the while loop again. Everything works well except the counter.  Somehow it keeps on entering the loop.

I know it works because when I set the counter to 1 it doesn't enter the loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open (ERRORLOG, ">>/usr/local/bin/log.log") || die "failed to open errorlog file \n$!\n\a";
open (MESSAGES, "tail -1 /var/adm/messages |") || die "failed to open alarms file \n$!\n\a";

my $date=`date +"%d/%m/%y-%H:%M"`;
my $num_of_messages_sent;

while (my $line = <MESSAGES>) {
    chomp($line);

    if ($line =~ m/inetd|ypserv|cront|sys|kern|panic|scsi|ipmp|mpathd/i && $num_of_messages_sent < 1){
        print ERRORLOG "$line\n";
        print "$line\n";
        print "$num_of_messages_sent\n";

        do something

        #$num_of_messages_sent = $num_of_messages_sent + 1;
        $num_of_messages_sent++;
    }

    #$num_of_messages_sent = $num_of_messages_sent + 1;
    #$num_of_messages_sent=0;
    print "$num_of_messages_sent\n";
}

#$num_of_messages_sent = $num_of_messages_sent + 1;
$num_of_messages_sent=0;

close (ERRORLOG);
close (MESSAGES);

-----------------------second code----------------------------------------

#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;


open (ERRORLOG, ">>/usr/local/bin/mcdl_errors.log") || die "failed to open errorlog file \n$!\n\a";
open (MESSAGES, "tail -1 /var/adm/messages | ") || die "failed to open alarms file \n$!\n\a";



## the last location checked is not at the end of messages file, we need to search the messages file

    #count how many messages you need to send in 1 minute. we permit only 4 messages
    #go over the messages file from the last location until the end

    my $date=`date +"%d/%m/%y-%H:%M"`;
    my $num_of_messages_sent=0;

    my $line2compare = `more /usr/local/bin/line.txt`;
    print "$line2compare\n";

    while (my $line = <MESSAGES>) {
    chomp($line);

    if ($line =~ m/ypserv|cront|sys|kern|panic|scsi|ipmp|mpathd/i){
    #print ERRORLOG "$line\n";
    print "$line\n";
    print "$num_of_messages_sent\n";

   if ($line ne $line2compare) {


   print ERRORLOG "$line\n";
   print "$line2compare\n";


   do something

    $num_of_messages_sent++;
    `echo $line > /usr/local/bin/line.txt`;

     } else {

    print "$line-Check this out\n";

    }

    print "$num_of_messages_sent\n";
    last if $num_of_messages_sent>0;

    }
}




close (ERRORLOG);
close (MESSAGES);
```

Comment: write `last;` after `$num_of_messages_sent++;`

Comment: thanks for your quick comment, but this didnt help.

Comment: can you post what's there in `do something`? Also are you sure it's going in `if` block? If it goes in `if` block and you have written `last` then it must break the loop, there's something else cooking, share the complete code.

Comment: Hi, the do something - is just sending sms with $line. this section works well but as i mentioned before, doesnt stop after one iteration.

Comment: Try putting exit there, that'll confirm.

Comment: I added the exit command after the last command but it doesnt help. thanks for your help.

Comment: That means your code is not going in `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just never enter the if condition because you do a `tail -1` on your file, which gives you only the last line of it. If this last line doesn't match the pattern, you don't enter the if condition and your while ends immediately, since there is just a single line in MESSAGES.

You can open your file like this:

```
open (MESSAGES, "/var/adm/messages") || die "failed to open alarms file \n$!\n\a";
```

remove the `&& $num_of_messages_sent < 1` in your if condition and add a `last if $num_of_messages_sent>0;` at the end of your loop like this :

```
while (my $line = <MESSAGES>) {
    chomp($line);

    if ($line =~ m/inetd|ypserv|cront|sys|kern|panic|scsi|ipmp|mpathd/i){
        print ERRORLOG "$line\n";
        print "$line\n";
        print "$num_of_messages_sent\n";

        do something

        $num_of_messages_sent++;
    }
    print "$num_of_messages_sent\n";
    last if $num_of_messages_sent>0;
}
```

PS: I don't know if it's intended in your regular expression, but the `|` character is considered as an OR. If you want to match the `|` character, you have to put a `\` before it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. i tried what you suggested but still the script acts the same. i'm trying to run it from crontab and it keeps on enterying the loop

Comment: @user2131714 It works for me. Did you put the `last if $num_of_messages_sent>0;` just before the while's closing brace ? (maybe my sentence wasn't very clear ^^). Also, as @david-d suggested, you should initialize $num_of_messages_sent to 0 since you use strict ;)

Comment: Thansk again. i tried it using cron but seems like in each iteration the counter turns back to 0 beacuse $num_of_messages_sent is set to 0 and go into the loop again for 1 time. i want it to stop after 1 iteration. i mean if $line=$line which means its the same line then the script sholud stop.

Comment: i tried this script (see second code above(i dont know how to enter a code into new comment)), but some how the $line is diffrent than $line2compare. when i print it the ouput of those 2 variables rae the same but when i run it from cron it keeps on entering the loop

Comment: Change your prints to see which one is actually printing what (for example, write `print "1st if : $num_of_messages_sent\n"`, etc...) and post the output.

Comment: Hi, my problem is that: my $line2compare = `more /usr/local/bin/line.txt`; is not equal to `echo $line > /usr/local/bin/line.txt`;
when i print both strings they look the same but there's something that make them diffrent and i dont know what it is

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

First use `tail -f` instead of `tail -1`. You're only reading one line of the output before you exit your loop. Using `tail -f` will *follow* the output, and your program will keep looping until you use a `last` statement.. The only problem is that if you don't use `last`, your loop will never exit. Instead, when the process that was writing that log dies, you'll sit there waiting forever for the line that never comes.

I get around this by also looking for some sort of ending statement that may be in my log. For example, if you're using Tomcat, you will probably see something about the application stopping. That should be your cue to exit the loop.

The other issue is that you're not initializing your counter:

```
 my $num_of_messages_sent;
```

When you attempt to increment that, you'll get a warning message, and your program may fail. Instead:

```
 my $num_of_messages_sent = 0;
```